# How does Rails 4 know which format to use for views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a app which receives requests as SOAP messages.

Let's say user sends SOAP message via POST method to address `my.app.com/push_notification`.

It my logs I see such line:

```
Processing by Service#push_notification as XML.
```

And Rails uses `push_notification.xml` as a view for this request.

One thing I don't get - by what information from the request does Rails know it has to render XML view?

I would understand if users would send request to `my.app.com/push_notification.xml`, but right now users are sending request to URL without the `.xml` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client.

Take a look at the request headers of a request (you can do that in your browser with the developer tools -> network tab). These headers will contain a key *Accept* that holds a value for all the formats the client (your browser) accepts for this request.

For a normal HTML webpage, it will look like:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

For a JSON ajax request, it will look like:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

In addition to this, Rails will also change the response format if you add a `format` to your url, like `products/index.xml`.